# SQL join select record from different date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables and I need to be able to update them going both ways, the first table is a list of SGD EXCHANGE RATE:

| CURRENCY | Date | RATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USD | 1/1/2011 | 1.2651 |
| USD | 15/1/2011 | 1.2611 |
| USD | 29/1/2011 | 1.2605 |
| USD | 12/2/2011 | 1.2581 |
| USD | 26/2/2011 | 1.2603 |
| AUD | 1/1/2011 | 1.3144 |
| AUD | 15/1/2011 | 1.3133 |
| AUD | 29/1/2011 | 1.3188 |
| AUD | 12/2/2011 | 1.3164 |
| AUD | 26/2/2011 | 1.3195 |

The second is a PAYMENT TRANSACTION :

| TRX DATE | CURRENCY | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2011 | AUD | 100 |
| 9/1/2011 | USD | 300 |
| 17/1/2011 | AUD | 400 |
| 17/1/2011 | USD | 500 |
| 21/1/2011 | AUD | 600 |
| 25/1/2011 | USD | 800 |
| 3/2/2011 | USD | 900 |
| 8/2/2011 | AUD | 200 |
| 13/2/2011 | USD | 300 |
| 18/2/2011 | USD | 500 |
| 21/2/2011 | AUD | 600 |
| 5/3/2011 | AUD | 900 |

I want join the "PAYMENT TRANSACTION" table to "SGD EXCHANGE RATE" table to get exchange rate for each transaction.

If the exchange rate for the "TRX DATE" is not found then use the latest available exchange rate before the "TRX DATE".

Below is the expecting result after two tables joined

| TRX DATE | CURRENCY | AMOUNT | RATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2011 | AUD | 100 | 1.3144 |
| 9/1/2011 | USD | 300 | 1.2651 |
| 17/1/2011 | AUD | 400 | 1.3133 |
| 17/1/2011 | USD | 500 | 1.2611 |
| 21/1/2011 | AUD | 600 | 1.3133 |
| 25/1/2011 | USD | 800 | 1.2611 |
| 3/2/2011 | USD | 900 | 1.2605 |
| 8/2/2011 | AUD | 200 | 1.3188 |
| 13/2/2011 | USD | 300 | 1.2581 |
| 18/2/2011 | USD | 500 | 1.2581 |
| 21/2/2011 | AUD | 600 | 1.3164 |
| 5/3/2011 | AUD | 900 | 1.3195 |

I'm using this to fill in the records where RATE is NULL

```sql
select Table_2.TRX_DATE, Table_2.CURRENCY, Table_2.AMOUNT, rate
from Table_2
left join Table_1 on Table_2.TRX_DATE >= Table_1.Tgl 
                  and Table_2.TRX_DATE <= Table_1.Tgl 
                  and Table_2.CURRENCY = Table_1.Currency
```

And, this is what I get:

| TRX DATE | CURRENCY | AMOUNT | RATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2011 | AUD | 100 | 1.3144 |
| 9/1/2011 | USD | 300 | NULL |
| 17/1/2011 | AUD | 400 | NULL |
| 17/1/2011 | USD | 500 | NULL |
| 21/1/2011 | AUD | 600 | NULL |
| 25/1/2011 | USD | 800 | NULL |
| 3/2/2011 | USD | 900 | NULL |
| 8/2/2011 | AUD | 200 | NULL |
| 13/2/2011 | USD | 300 | NULL |
| 18/2/2011 | USD | 500 | NULL |
| 21/2/2011 | AUD | 600 | NULL |
| 5/3/2011 | AUD | 900 | NULL |

Comment: FYI; taking the time to check your post is well formatting *before* you press submit goes a *along* way to having your question well received. The preview is there to enable you to see what the post **should** look like before you submit it, so if it looks malformed in the preview it likely will when you post it.

Comment: thank you for correcting my question, i will keep that in mind to use preview before posting next time

Answer (score 0):

Sample data

```
CREATE TABLE CURRENCY (
    CURR varchar(100) NULL,
    [DATE] date NULL,
    RATE float NULL
);

CREATE TABLE TRANSACTIONS (
    TR_DATE date NULL,
    CURR varchar(100) NULL,
    AMOUNT float NULL
);

INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS (TR_DATE, CURR, AMOUNT) VALUES('2011-01-01', N'AUD', 100.0);
INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS (TR_DATE, CURR, AMOUNT) VALUES('2011-01-09', N'USD', 300.0);
INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS (TR_DATE, CURR, AMOUNT) VALUES('2011-01-17', N'AUD', 400.0);
INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS (TR_DATE, CURR, AMOUNT) VALUES('2011-01-17', N'USD', 500.0);
INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS (TR_DATE, CURR, AMOUNT) VALUES('2011-01-21', N'AUD', 600.0);
INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS (TR_DATE, CURR, AMOUNT) VALUES('2011-01-25', N'USD', 800.0);
INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS (TR_DATE, CURR, AMOUNT) VALUES('2011-02-03', N'USD', 900.0);
INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS (TR_DATE, CURR, AMOUNT) VALUES('2011-02-08', N'AUD', 200.0);
INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS (TR_DATE, CURR, AMOUNT) VALUES('2011-02-13', N'USD', 300.0);
INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS (TR_DATE, CURR, AMOUNT) VALUES('2011-02-18', N'USD', 500.0);
INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS (TR_DATE, CURR, AMOUNT) VALUES('2011-02-21', N'AUD', 600.0);
INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS (TR_DATE, CURR, AMOUNT) VALUES('2011-02-05', N'AUD', 900.0);

INSERT INTO CURRENCY (CURR, [DATE], RATE) VALUES(N'USD', '2011-01-01', 1.2651);
INSERT INTO CURRENCY (CURR, [DATE], RATE) VALUES(N'USD', '2011-01-15', 1.2611);
INSERT INTO CURRENCY (CURR, [DATE], RATE) VALUES(N'USD', '2011-01-29', 1.2605);
INSERT INTO CURRENCY (CURR, [DATE], RATE) VALUES(N'USD', '2011-02-12', 1.2581);
INSERT INTO CURRENCY (CURR, [DATE], RATE) VALUES(N'USD', '2011-02-26', 1.2603);
INSERT INTO CURRENCY (CURR, [DATE], RATE) VALUES(N'AUD', '2011-01-01', 1.3144);
INSERT INTO CURRENCY (CURR, [DATE], RATE) VALUES(N'AUD', '2011-01-15', 1.3133);
INSERT INTO CURRENCY (CURR, [DATE], RATE) VALUES(N'AUD', '2011-01-29', 1.3188);
INSERT INTO CURRENCY (CURR, [DATE], RATE) VALUES(N'AUD', '2011-02-12', 1.3164);
INSERT INTO CURRENCY (CURR, [DATE], RATE) VALUES(N'AUD', '2011-02-26', 1.3195);
```

Sample SQL Query:

```
SELECT T.*, C.RATE FROM TRANSACTIONS T 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT T1.CURR, T1.[DATE] as MINDATE, T2.[DATE] as MAXDATE, T1.RATE FROM 
    (
        SELECT CURR, [DATE], RATE, 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (order by CURR, [DATE]) as NUM 
        FROM CURRENCY T1
    ) T1 
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            CURR, [DATE], RATE, 
            ROW_NUMBER() over (order by CURR, [DATE]) as NUM 
        FROM CURRENCY
    ) T2 on T1.NUM + 1 = T2.NUM 
) C ON T.CURR = C.CURR AND T.TR_DATE >= C.MINDATE AND T.TR_DATE < C.MAXDATE


Result: 
TR_DATE     CURR    AMOUNT  RATE
2011-01-01  AUD     100     1.3144
2011-01-09  USD     300     1.2651
2011-01-17  AUD     400     1.3133
2011-01-17  USD     500     1.2611
2011-01-21  AUD     600     1.3133
2011-01-25  USD     800     1.2611
2011-02-03  USD     900     1.2605
2011-02-08  AUD     200     1.3188
2011-02-13  USD     300     1.2581
2011-02-18  USD     500     1.2581
2011-02-21  AUD     600     1.3164
2011-02-05  AUD     900     1.3188
```

Comment: It's works: https://sqlize.online/s/X Thank you